# MySQL how to create a trigger to push data if record updates from another table

Tags: mysql

Here is a db-fiddle link:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e8dK8LcfkVAyfuN1tEtmfb/2

**How do I create a trigger to do the following (2 actions):**

**Action 1** - If a new record appears in table_one - then it will insert a new record into history.

e.g.

table_one:

```
 insert into table_one (text_field) values ('Option1');
```

**Output:**

**table_one:**

```
id   text_field
1     Option1
```

**History table:**

```
id   table_oneID   new_text_field  old_text_field1   old_text_field2
1        1            Option1
```

and so on.

**Action 2 -**

If I update table_one like so:

```
update table_one set text_field = 'New Text' where id = 1;
```

**table_one becomes:**

```
id   text_field
1     New Text
```

**History becomes**

```
id   table_oneID   new_text_field  old_text_field1   old_text_field2
1        1            New Text         Option1
```

It pushes the old text back and new text at the front.

How can these two action be achieved using a trigger?

Comment: 'using a trigger'  they can't you need 2 triggers one after insert one after update

Comment: I would redesign your history table so that you don't have multiple old_text_fields.

Comment: @P.Salmon how would you redesign it? - I'll be more than happy to hear it!

Comment: For simplicity I would have  id  , table_column, oneID ,  oldvalue , newvalue  timestamp (so that I knew when it happened) where column is the name of the column that was changed.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's good, but regarding pushing the data back.. is that possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 triggers:

AFTER INSERT on table_one with next query:

```
INSERT INTO history_table (table_oneID, new_text_field) 
VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.text_field);
```

AFTER UPDATE on table_one with next query:

```
UPDATE history_table SET
    old_text_field7 =  old_text_field6,
    old_text_field6 =  old_text_field5,
    old_text_field5 =  old_text_field4,
    old_text_field4 =  old_text_field3,
    old_text_field3 =  old_text_field2,
    old_text_field2 =  old_text_field1,
    old_text_field1 =  NEW.text_field
WHERE table_oneID = NEW.id;
```